# FindControl inside Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to find a Label inside a Repeater, I am using:

```
    protected void lnkbtnEditRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        salesEditPanel.Visible = true;
        resultPanel.Visible = false;
        zipPanel.Visible = false;
        ddlPanel.Visible = false;
        topPanel.Visible = false;

        Label lblSalesId = (Label)(Repeater2.Items[0].FindControl("lblSalesID"));

        DataView dv = FillSalesPersonForm(Convert.ToInt32(lblSalesId.Text));

        frmViewSalesPeople.DataSource = dv;
        frmViewSalesPeople.DataBind();

    }
```

This works great if the repeater only has one result, but if it has more then one it only gets the id for the first item listed. Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: Basically the return is filled with user info and with each user info is a link to another page. So when I click the link I want to get the ID from the label for the record the link was clicked for. So If I click record 4 out of 5 I want and the ID for record 4 is 900 I want to get the 900 to pass.

Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you telling it to only get the first item by using Repeater2.Items[**0**].FindControl... ?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptItems.Items)
{
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var lbl= (Label)item.FindControl("lblMyLabel");

        lbl.Text = "do something to your label";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell on what you're trying to do, you have two options:

1) This code should be modified and placed in the repeater's ItemCommand event handler

2) If this lnkbtnEditRecord is a control in the repeater Item, then the `sender` object passed in should have it's parent (or parent's parent, etc) be a RepeaterItem, which should contain your lblSalesId control

Either way, we'd need more information on the scenario and what you're trying to do

Comment: Added some more info, might explain it better. Thanks!